# How to achieve transmitting arbitrary signal based on a schedule

Tags: unetstack

In my case, I want to wake up the subnero modem in specific time and transmit the signal generated by myself. According to the unetStack handbook Chapter 25, **scheduler** module has the ability to organize the modem wakeup at a specific time. So I tried to test the modem by using follow groovy script. Without no doubt, it not works.

```
addsleep 1.minutes.later 5.minutes.later;
phy << new GetSleepScheduleReq();
plvl = -30;
signal = load('sig.txt');
5.times {
    phy << new TxBasebandSignalReq(signal:signal, fc:0);
    delay(5000);
}
```

I found there is a function named “WakeFromSleepNtf’, which would be helpful to control the modem, however, no detail illustration about such function.

Although the **delay** function or the parameter, named **TxTime**, of **TxBasebandSignalReq** can be used to make a schedule to control the modem working in a specific timeline, it requires the modem works all the time. In this way, the battery of the modem is a concern, especially when the modem is integrated with a vehicle.

I believe that if there is a notifying function or other method to realize run my script automatically when the subnero waked up, then the problem can be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but have some details incorrect. If I understand correctly, you want to sleep for 5 minutes and then transmit a signal 5 times with a delay of 5 seconds between transmissions.

If so, I would do something like this on the shell:

```
// part 1: wait until its time to transmit
t = 5.minutes.later                  // calculate time of transmission
addsleep t                           // schedule sleep from now until time t
while (t-time/1000 > 1) delay(1000)  // wait until its time to transmit

// part 2: make your transmissions
plvl -30                             // set power level
signal = load('sig.txt')             // load your signal
5.times {                            // transmit it 5 times with 5 second delay
    phy << new TxBasebandSignalReq(signal:signal, fc:0)
    delay(5000)
}
```

The first part of the code computes the time `t` (in epoch seconds) at which transmission should be made, and asks the modem to schedule a sleep until then. Putting the modem to sleep takes a few seconds, so the script will continue running during this time. Hence we need the next statement to wait until it's time to transmit, by checking the current time (`time` gives current time in epoch milliseconds) against the transmit time every second.

The second part of the code is the same as yours, but do note there should be no `=` after `plvl`.

P.S.  Some modems (e.g. `unet audio` on laptop) may not have low power sleep mode, so might not really sleep. The wait loop in part 1 also ensures that this code works correctly on such modems.

Comment: Hi Dr. Chitre, thanks for your detailed explanation! I have test the code on the laptop simulator (unet audio), it works!

Comment: Great! I haven't had a chance to test on modem before posting the answer. Once you test it out on the modem, and if it works, would you please mark the answer as accepted? Thanks.

Comment: Sure! I will test it in Monday.

Comment: Hi Dr. Chitre, something wrong with me. Because I use the WSL(windows subsystem for linux) test the code by using unet audio,  the program was run on windows system, actually. Therefore, I use the debug message (generated by 'println') to check  the code. The program is running as I think, however, I can't hear the signal (generated by 'cw(2000, 1, 0)') when I use ubuntu system, and then the unet audio do not works when we try other commands (such as 'tell 0, 'hi''). When we restart the unet audio 2-3 times, the unet audio works again. However, when run myscript.groovy, it fails to work again.

Comment: @XiaopingHong, I'm not sure I understand what problem you're facing from the description in your comment. Are you referring to `unet audio` simply not working at all, or are you referring to this solution for your specific question on scheduling transmissions?

Comment: Yes. Some strange things happened! When I tried to run the code you showed in Ubuntu 18.04 with `unet audio`, the `portaudio device` failed to work. I cannot hear the signal by my ear. So, I tried to debug the code using the `println` to check the program works or not. Then I found the program run as I thought, however, the sound of the signal cannot be heard. That's why I said the program works at the first time, because I just watch the `println` information. I am sorry for my poor description.

Comment: So, I do not try with the modem right now due to I am not sure does it damage to the system file of the modem. Moreover, when the `portaudio dev` failed to work, several times restart were needed to make `unet aduio` works again.

Comment: If the `println` works but you don't hear anything from the speaker (check your volume setting), you may have a problem with the portaudio installation on your machine.

Comment: The `portaudio dev` works. I checked the demo you showed again, and I found that `addsleep t` (line 3) can be commented out. Then I ran the program and the sound transmitted by laptop can be heard. However, the problem is that the device can not sleep in the end. I have upgraded the laptop to `ubuntu 19.04`, the results are same. Maybe there is an incompatibility between `portaudio` and `addsleep`. For the modem test, the `delay` function was finally used to setup a schedule manually.

Comment: Portaudio on laptop does not support low-power mode (so `addsleep` will not work on laptop to put laptop to low-power mode).